# how to insert string into query in python pymysql

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I have a following query:

```py
cursor = connection.cursor()

query = """
        SELECT *
        FROM `my_database`.table_a

        """
result = cursor.execute(query)
```

which works as expected. But I need to change `my_database` in `cursor.execute`. I try:

```py
cursor = connection.cursor()

query = """
             SELECT *
             FROM %s.table_a

             """
result = cursor.execute(query, ("my_database",))
```

which gives an error `pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''my_database'.table_a         at line 2")`

how can I insert database name in `cursor.execute` please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to bind a database name (or any other database object name) using a placeholder in a prepared statement.  This would be, among other problems, a security risk.  However, you might be able to use an f-string here instead:

```py
cursor = connection.cursor()

db_name = "my_database"
query = f"""
         SELECT *
         FROM {db_name}.table_a
         """
result = cursor.execute(query)
```

It should also be mentioned that the above is only SQL injection safe if you are certain that the database name is *not* coming from outside your own application.